# Why am I getting "NOAUTH Authentication required" with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I have a simple redis server running with a password. I want to talk with it from my spring boot app. I look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html) and see there is a `spring.redis.password` so my application-local.yml (running with `-Dspring.profiles.active=local`) looks like...

```
spring:
  redis:
    password: ...
```

but when I run I get

> NOAUTH Authentication required

What am I missing? I can connect via node.js like...

```
import redis from "redis";

const client = redis.createClient({
 password: "..."
});
```

**Additional Code**

```
@Bean
LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(){
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration config = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(config);
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(){
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
    return template;
}
```

also tried...

```
@Bean
LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(){
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration config = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
    if (redisPassword != null){
        config.setPassword(redisPassword);
    }
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(config);
}
```

and this works but seems overly verbose given it is a standard property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need less verbose configuration, you can remove `RedisConnectionFactory` bean from your configuration code and just inject the `RedisConnectionFactory` bean in your `redisTemplate`. `redisConnectionFactory` will be populated with properties from application.yml:

```
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
    return template;
}
```

In this case, Spring injects `LettuceConnectionFactory` by default.

The problem was here: `new RedisStandaloneConfiguration()`. If you look at the code of constructor you will see that empty password is created and there is no way to set it besides calling a setter.

---

**Old answer:** You need to fetch your data from `application.yml` through `RedisProperties` class. Try this:

```
@Bean
RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(RedisProperties props) {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration config = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();

    config.setPassword(props.getPassword());

    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(config);
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
    return template;
}
```

Here `props` contains properties from `spring.redis` section

Comment: Right but this seems verbose why isn't it auto configured if it is a default property? For example I don't have to set the host to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Also this answer in general is overly verbose see my version it doesn't require anything but password to be set.

Comment: Host and port are auto-configured, I put them just in case you need to launch your service with redis not on localhost:6379. Password should be set manually

Comment: Updated my answer with less verbose config

Comment: Now the updated answer doesn't include the section for the password rt? That was the solution to the original question

Comment: It does not include the section for password. The answer to original question is remove `RedisConnectionFactory` bean and let Spring create a one for you. Created `RedisConnectionFactory` is populated with properties from application.yml

Answer (score 1):

My app was running alright with Spring Boot **v2.2.4.RELEASE**. After migrating to Spring **v3.1.1**, the same problem occured as author mentions.

I tried several approaches including the answer proposed by **nkrivenko** which **worked**. However, here is the solution that I found afterwards and finally accept as **correct**:

In **application.yaml** (.property) file I previously had:

```
spring:
  redis:
    client-name: JEDIS
    timeout: 3000
    port: ${REDIS_PORT:6379}
    host: ${REDIS_HOSTNAME:localhost}
    password: ${REDIS_PASSWORD:theRedisPasswordHere}
```

Thanks to IntelliJ IDEA that suggested this structure is **deprecated**. As it recommends just add **data:** line between **spring:** and **redis:** lines. Now it looks like and **works** without any code change:

```
spring:
  data:
    redis:
      client-name: JEDIS
      timeout: 3000
      port: ${REDIS_PORT:6379}
      host: ${REDIS_HOSTNAME:localhost}
      password: ${REDIS_PASSWORD:theRedisPasswordHere}
```

Edited: thanks to **Mustafa Güven**'s comment

Comment: adding data: between spring: and redis: in yaml solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

for me, problem because version of spring and redis (2.1.4), after upgrade newer version, it work normal
Please use with:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I use redis sentinel and my properties is:

```
spring.redis.database=0
spring.redis.sentinel.master=
spring.redis.sentinel.nodes=
spring.redis.sentinel.password=
spring.redis.password=
spring.redis.timeout=60000
```